# Java SOAP Server that can be deployed in Tomcat, JBoss, Geronimo, etc. etc. etc

Tags: java, soap

I'm hoping to create a Java SOAP server which I can deploy in Tomcat, or in JBoss, or in Geronimo, or in XYZ, etc. etc. etc.

Bottom line, it should have the least dependencies possible. I'm trying to avoid libraries outside of what's included in a standard java distro because of licensing/packaging/reusability issues.

Can any provide a link to where I should start looking, or some example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 1.6 introduced the possibility to create standard SOAP webservices with the standard JDK.

There are many examples on the web, for example http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/12/12/webservices-jdk-6

IDEs like NetBeans also call the necessary tools (apt) automatically which makes it very easy to get started.

However I did not research how well this will work across all available containers.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Axis2 (http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) should provide what you're looking for, or JAX-WS (https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) if you want more lightweight.

Comment: Right, except them I'm depending on Axis. Is there a way to do this *without* other dependencies/packages?

Comment: Are you saying you want a SOAP server from JBoss, Tomcat, or Geronimo? Or are you asking if there's one that could be used in ALL of JBoss, Tomcat, Geronimo?

Your options are (a) implement it yourself, (b) use an implementation from one of those containers, or (c) use a standalone implementation.

Comment: I am asking if there is one that can be used in ALL of JBoss, Tomcat, and Geronimo, *and* is part of the standard java libs/distro. I would prefer *not* to depend on anything JBoss, Tomcat, Geronimo, or anything else that isn't part of the standard Java package.

Answer (score 1):

Wow.

http://www.w3.org/TR/soap/

There's the standard. You will be spending a *lot* of time on this project. You'll need to also check out the HTTP and XML specs to build those components.

Ignoring XFire and Axis2 is an very very expensive choice...

Answer (score 0):

I recently used Metro 1.4 for this (an open source glassfish component) which implements the standard approach for web services.

Drop in the jars in a Java 5 web container, annotate your class and method with standard @tags, and let Metro do the rest.

I have been very pleased with performance in a Jetty container.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring web service module you don't need Axis or XFire.  I think it's a good way to go if you're already using Spring.